# XDocument.Descendants returning null values

Tags: xml, linq

I am thinking I am doing something wrong here.  I am using XDocument.Descendants to get a grandchild element of an xml file that I am trying to parse into an object.  But I am getting a null value every time I attempt to run it.

```cs
IEnumerable<PatientClass> template = (IEnumerable<PatientClass>)(from templates in xDocument.Descendants("dataTemplateSpecification")
select new PatientClass
{
  PatientId = int.Parse(templates.Descendants("element").Single(el => el.Attribute("name").Value=="PatientId").ToString()),
  EMPIID = int.Parse(templates.Descendants("element").Single(el => el.Attribute("name").Value=="EMPIID").ToString())                  
});
```

Let us suppose that that was the extent of the linq query that I am using...

```
<dataTemplateSpecification id="id1" name="name1" >
<templates xmlns="">
<template>
  <elements>
    <element id="element0" name="PatientId" display="Patient ID" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="false" value="4563">
      <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/PATIENT_ID" />
    </element>
    <element id="element1" name="PopulationPatientID" display="Population Patient ID" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="true" enc="2098" value="6407">
      <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/POPULATION_PATIENT_ID" />
    </element>
    <element id="element2" name="EMPIID" display="EMPIID" dataType="String" visable="true" readOnly="true" value="">
      <mapping path="//Template/TemplateData/ACOData/EMPI" />
    </element>        
  </elements>
</template>
</templates>
</dataTemplateSpecification>
```

Let us suppose that that is the xml that I am using...  now, would I need namespaces to get that above query to work?  I hope not.  that would mean that I would have to rewrite my xml... Which would really, really be rough for me.

Comment: you could try `xDocument.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "dataTemplateSpecification");` to test your namespaces question.

Comment: Please clean up your code before posting it. You've got commented-out code in there, and how wide does code have to be before you insert a line break?

Comment: Your code throws a `FormatException` on the `int.Parse()`, because you are trying to parse the whole element to an `int`, which won't work. But it does not return `null` for me. Is `dataTemplateSpecification` really the root of your document? If not, does the real root have any `xmlns` attributes?

Comment: svick It does not have any namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. It looks like you're trying to parse an XML element to an integer. The below code works for me, but I had to give the element with name `EMPIID` an integer in the `value` attribute.

Please note, though, that there is probably a better way to do what you're trying to do. I just tried to get as close to your original code as possible with my example.

```
var xel = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(xml);
var elements = xel.Descendants("elements");

var patients = elements.Select(e => new
{
    PatientID = int.Parse(e.Elements("element")
        .First(el => el.Attribute("name").Value == "PatientId")
        .Attribute("value").Value),
    EMPIID = int.Parse(e.Elements("element")
        .First(el => el.Attribute("name").Value == "EMPIID")
        .Attribute("value").Value)
});
```

Comment: Why did you use .First there?  I guess you are looking for the first element.  I am not necessarily looking for the first element.  Really confused by Linq syntax

Comment: @DmainEvent -- .First gives you the first element in the collection that matches the predicate. .Single does the same, but it throws an error if any other elements in the collection match the predicate.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to handle an empty string if you are looking for an integer would you?  That is the situation I currently find myself in.

Comment: @DmainEvent -- You need to check if the value is empty. { if string.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Attribute("value").Value) ... }. Linq may not be the best solution to your problem. Try using a foreach loop instead.